# How to pass data-structure residing in memory from module to module

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, memory-management

I am writing a code, wherein I will store few files into the data-structure in memory, and will then use that data-structure in all the modules in order to access that data-structure. (time-saving)

Since the code is written in python, and is very big so its very hard to pass that data-structure from function-to-function.

Is there any possible way that I store the file-to-data-structure at the start of the code, and then I can use that data structure in any module, as that data structure is residing in the memory during the program execution.

Please help. Extremely important..!!

Let me give an example.

> > main.py ..... This is the start of the project, here I store the complete file-into-datastructure.
> >     other_module.py ..... This is some other module, where in i want to access that data structure which must be residing in the memory, as main.py is in execution and it had called other_module.py.

Notice, I cannot store file-to-data structure thing inside other_module because then it would be very time-consuming, as here i am giving a very small example, but I am actually dealing with a bigger problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python variables and function arguments are always only references to objects, so don't worry about passing a large data structure as a function argument: the data is not copied, only a new reference is created.

However, if you know your code will always deal with only a single instance of the data structure, you can store it in a global variable. You could create a separate module that loads the data into a module-level variable, and import that module to main.py and other_module.py.

Answer (score 1):

> and is very big so its very hard to pass that data-structure from function-to-function.

No, it isn't. Python variables don't work that way. You implicitly get a pointer.